# About the do-while statment with switch

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "1. Facebook" << endl;
    cout << "2. Twitter" << endl;
    cout << "3. Instagram" << endl;
    cout << "4. SnapChat" << endl;

    int input;

    do {
        cout << "Enter a selection > ";
        cin >> input;
        switch(input) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Facebook is Loading..." << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Twitter is Loading..." << endl;
        case 3:
            cout << "Instagram is Loading..." << endl;
        case 4:
            cout << "SnapChat is Loading..." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong Selection" << endl;
        }
    }while(input =! 1 && input =! 2 && input != 3 && input != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to retry the progress if I got the wrong selection and I got confused and dunno what to do, so can someone tell me what I should do so I can make it?

Comment: It seems from your question that you have compiling code, yet what you've shown doesn't compile (*error: expression is not assignable* from the equivalent of `(!1 && input) = ...`).

Comment: what has higher precedence, `=!` or `-->`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly...

```
input =! 1 && input =! 2 && input != 3 && input != 4
```

... those `=!` should be `!=`.

Secondly, if someone types non-numeric input, `cin >> input` will fail and all future input attempts will instantly fail - without even waiting for the user to type anything further.  You need to clear the error state and ignore any bad input characters remaining in the stream - say up to the end of the line:

```
default:
    cout << "Wrong Selection" << endl;
    std::cin.clear(); // clear error state
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');.
```

You'll need to `#include <limits>` atop your program to use `std::numeric_limts<>`.

Separately, you're first two `case` statements lack a `break` and will fall through to execute the following `case`(s) code....

---

I'd recommend explicitly checking `cin >> input` for success too, though with C++11 it guarantees to set `input` to `0` on failure so it will work reliably.  With C++03 there's no such guarantee and you may get arbitrary garbage left in `input` after a failure, which might coincidentally match one of the `case`s.  To handle this explicitly:

```
if (!(cin >> input)) input = -1; // sentinel meaning erroneous
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you add your breaks after each case if you want the switch statement to break/exit. Else everything underneath is going to be executed.
Also you mixed up the != (does not equal) and wrote =!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "1. Facebook" << endl;
    cout << "2. Twitter" << endl;
    cout << "3. Instagram" << endl;
    cout << "4. SnapChat" << endl;

    int input;

    do {
        cout << "Enter a selection > ";
        cin >> input;
        switch(input) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Facebook is Loading..." << endl;
            break;  
        case 2:
            cout << "Twitter is Loading..." << endl;
            break;  // add break
        case 3:
            cout << "Instagram is Loading..." << endl;
            break;  // add break
        case 4:
            cout << "SnapChat is Loading..." << endl;
            break;  // add break
        default:
            cout << "Wrong Selection" << endl;
        }
    } while(input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4); // != not =!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to add relevant explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break` statement after each `case`:

```
case 2:
cout << "Twitter is Loading..." << endl;
break; 
case 3:
cout << "Instagram is Loading..." << endl;
break;
```

Change `=!` to `!=`

```
while(input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4);
```